TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eth') of web3
I'm getting the following error when trying to instantiate a contract using Web3.js:
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'eth')

Source
Ethereum\election_factory.js (4:22) @ web3

  2 | import ElectionFactory from './Build/ElectionFact.json';
  3 |
> 4 | const instance = new web3.eth.Contract(
    |                      ^
  5 |   JSON.parse(ElectionFactory.interface),
  6 |     '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266'
  7 | );


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How did you instantiate web3?
If this is a test, you should have something that looks like this:
const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const ganache = require('ganache');

const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

If it is in the browser, you should have something like this instead:
import { Web3 } from "web3";

const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum)

Maybe you forgot to pass in the provider, or maybe you did not create an instance and just tried to use the default import directly?
